# Custom Objects in JTree

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have a main frame that acts as a container for my modules form panels. All these forms are not displayed modal model but within the left side of my frame.

I have managed to get the left pane of my main frame updated with whichever panel that corresponds with a tree selection without using the CardLayout.

Below is a structure of my JTree panel currently:

```
Clients
 |
 --- New clients
 |
 --- Manage Clients
Projects
 |
 --- New project
 |
 --- Manage Projects
```

In my current implementation I have been forced to name my subitems uniquely in order for me to be able to create the respective instance of the JPanel.

What I am looking for is to rather use Objects instead where I can have set and get methods to access which module a subitem belongs to, the its respective panel and so forth.

An example of such an object would be:

```
class TreeItem{

  private String id;

  private String label;

  private String module;

  private boolean isActive;

  //Rest of the class omitted...    
}
```

This would allow me to replace the sub-items label e.g. New clients with New and New projects to New without having to worry about which module the tree instance belongs to since I will be having an id field of the object itself as an identifier. Also the isActive field would help me deactivate all the tree items that are in active for a particular use say they cannot create a project for example but can update only.

For now all the information I have gathered on the internet is as confusing as 1 + 1 in creche.

Any advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"Any advice would be most appreciated,"*  Ask a question.  If there **is** a question buried in that collection of words above, add a '?' to it.  *"thanks in advance."*  You're welcome (in advance).

Comment: There actually is sorry for my poor wording. I know that I have to create a custom TreeModel for this and implement some sort of object collection be it vectors or whatever I choose but I really have no idea where to start given the requirements I have tried to enumerate in my collection of words. Like what kind of interfaces should I be aware of when building this custom tree and how I can leverage the existing library in achieving this.

Comment: Why not use **DefaultMutableTreeNode** which has a custom data object for your data.

Comment: Thanks Joop. I have been using it but as I mentioned I am not really aware of its strengths and benefits let alone the fact that I could use it with custom objects. Honest truth I am a PHP developer and only did Java for a year at varsity 2009 and now I am trying to build a PHP-Java system interfaced with RESTFul Web Services so I am rusty when it comes to Java. Thanks for your point will dig deeper on that class.

Comment: @LuyandaSiko building a custom TreeModel is relatively easy, but how you build it depends on what your datastructure looks like and how you'd like it to appear in the JTree. Take a look at two that I built: http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/tree/

Comment: @ControlAltDel Thanks for the pointer. I have gotten your files and sure will not forget to put  your link up for referencing in my thesis. I know this is achievable but I am not sure how to go about doing it so I will come back here and share with you guys my solution. Thank you.